# The reduce method sets the accumulator as array's first item if no initial value is given

Tags: javascript

Although the initial value of a reduce function is [marked as optional](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), it seems that if one doesn't supply it the reducer will initialize the accumulator with the first item of the input array. Why is it?

```
const output = Object.keys({
  name: "david",
  age: 30
}).reduce((memo, key) => {
  return [...memo, key];
})

console.log(output);

// output: ["n", "a", "m", "e", "age"]
```

vs

```
const output = Object.keys({
  name: "david",
  age: 30
}).reduce((memo, key) => {
  return [...memo, key];
}, [])

console.log(output);

// output: ["name", "age"]
```

The specific code example is just to illustrate the issue, I am aware that using Object.keys without reduce would return the same result. Tested with Chrome 68.

Comment: What do you think it would use instead of the first item?

Comment: Perhaps undefined?

Comment: "*Why is it?*" - because that's how `reduce` works! From the very MDN page you linked: "*If no initial value is supplied, **the first element in the array will be used**. Calling reduce() on an empty array without an initial value is an error.*" Not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Ok, it just seems like an illogical choice. I mean if you use flowType or typescript this clearly means that the first argument, which is expected to be the accumulator, can be one of the array's items instead. I wonder what is behind that choice. A bit philosophical, I know. I guess I'll just remember to add null to the initialValue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reduce` can be defined recursively, like:

```
// <Except some details to do with empty slots>
Array.prototype.reduce = function(f, initial_value) {
    if (this.length === 0) {
        if (arguments.length > 1) {
            return initial_value;
        }
        throw TypeError('reduce of empty array with no initial value');
    }
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
        // Starting value given.
        const copy = this.slice();
        const first = copy.shift();
        return copy.reduce(f, f(initial_value, first));
    } else {
        // No starting value given
        // What should happen here?
        const copy = this.slice();
        const first = copy.shift();
        // return copy.reduce(f, f(intial_value, first));

        // Nothing was given as the initial_value.
        // What is the same as "nothing"?
        // Applying the function with an `identity` value
        // so that `f(identity, first) === first` means
        // that this `identity` is the same as nothing.

        // Of course, we can't know what that is if there
        // are no elements in the list, so we threw an error before.
        return copy.reduce(f, first);
    }
};
```

In general, the second argument to `reduce` should be that identity element. For a function like `(a, b) => a + b`, that would be `0`. For `(a, b) => a * b`, it would be `1`. For `(a, b) => Math.max(a, b)`, it would be `-Infinity`.

For your function, it would be, as you correctly wrote, `[]`.

In general, the initial value is supposed to be that `identity`. So if you don't give a default, `reduce` will go on as if you gave it the identity of the function.

In your case, it's slightly more complex, as the function only has an "identity" if you define "equality" so that `(Input) x === (Output) [x]`.

See [the reduce function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

The spread operator (`...memo`) converts the first value to an array of characters. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

> Note: If initialValue isn't provided, reduce() will execute the
>   callback function starting at index 1, skipping the first index. If
>   initialValue is provided, it will start at index 0.

So, without an initial value, you could do this. Not that I think it's better, but it demonstrates the cited behavior

```js
const output = Object.keys({
  name: "david",
  age: 30,
  shoesize: 45
}).reduce((memo, key, i) => (i < 2 ? [memo] : memo).concat(key));
//                           ^ so convert the first value to array
console.log(output);
```