# Can you use reduce() on a nodelist?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I thought `reduce` might help me solve with minimal code a simple check on a nodelist, but I could not find out if I can't make it work or I overlooked some limitation of `reduce` like 'it doesn't work on a nodelist'.

This is what I tried so far:

**Html:**

```
<input class="form-check-input typeOfRepetition" type="radio" id="r1">
<input class="form-check-input typeOfRepetition" type="radio" id="r2">
<input class="form-check-input typeOfRepetition" type="radio" id="r2">
```

**JS**

```
typeOfRepetition__all= document.querySelectorAll('.typeOfRepetition')

const reducer = (acc, currV) => acc + (currV.checked ? 1 : 0)
const choiceChecked = els.typeOfRepetition__all.reduce(reducer);

if (choiceChecked) {
   //...do some stuff
}
```

I tried the approach of using reduce with a ternary operator check inside the [MDN sandbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and it worked well, i.e.:

```
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + ( currentValue % 2 ? 1 : 0);

// 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 becomes 1 + 0 + 1 + 0 = 2
console.log(array1.reduce(reducer));
```

but I could not figure out why it doesn't apply on my original idea. `forEach` works well with that nodelist/array, so I was expecting it to work ok with `reduce` too.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**: Before posting I tried using `Array.from()` on the nodelist resulting from `querySelectorAll` and it got me a bit further: `reduce` works, yet rather than computing a clean numerical output (i.e. a zero or one response) it gives me something like

```
console.log('choiceChecked:', choiceChecked)
// choiceChecked: [object HTMLInputElement]10
// or
// choiceChecked: [object HTMLInputElement]00
```

Maybe I should stop trying to code so late at night :P

Comment: You need an initial value for `reduce`.

Comment: Yes, you should use `Array.from`. And you must not forget to pass an initial value for the accumulator (`0` in your case)!

Comment: (can't find a duplicate but this is a close match: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51898891/the-reduce-method-sets-the-accumulator-as-arrays-first-item-if-no-initial-value)

Comment: Yes that's close @user202729 but not an easy read :D I think the two answers below are much cleaner and complete.

Answer (score 7):

Yes you'll need to use `Array.from` on the node list to use `reduce` on it.

The reason you get `[object HTMLInputElement]10` from your reducer is that the first time it runs, `acc` is set to the first node (not the first node's `checked` property). From then on, it seems to try to concatenate the `0`s and `1`s with that node *as strings*. That first node coerced to a string is `'[object HTMLInputElement]'`. Then concatenated with the other two values it's `'[object HTMLInputElement]10'`.

You need to pass an initial value of `0` to `reduce`:

```js
Array.from(typeOfRepetition__all).reduce(reducer, 0);
```

That way, the initial value of `acc` will be `0`, not the first node. Also note it will now iterate three times, not just twice.

However, it seems like you're just trying to count the number of checked radio buttons of a certain class. Why not just do:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.typeOfRepetition:checked').length
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation @weltschmerz a) I think I finally wrapped my head around `reduce` and b) code now works a charm. I knew the string was a matter of coercion and I had read about the initial value thing but I must have missed the placeholder for the desired initial value of the accumulator.

Answer (score 4):

just do

```
const choiceChecked = [...document.querySelectorAll('.typeOfRepetition')]
                      .reduce((a,c)=>a+(c.checked?1:0),0 );
```

Comment: Holy. Code is beautiful. Could you add an explanation on how the spread operator gets into making this work? If you do I will be really conflicted about assigning the selected choice (sigh). I would assume it replaces the `Array.from()`, is that correct?

Comment: @GiampaoloFerradini yes, it replace  `Array.from()`, but the first trick is to help memory magnement by doing evrything in one compact code.

Comment: How does the memory footprint differ from the original code in the question?

Comment: @MisterJojo While it is true that the original code uses three variables and you only use one, the comparison strikes me as very minimal memory overhead. And the execution stack should already be empty at the end of that code. I don't think the garbage collector touches the execution stack, or that it ever needs to, but I may well be wrong as I'm no expert on garbage collection. But sooner or later the garbage collector should clean up your `choiceChecked` variable, too.

Comment: You said your answer provided a memory improvement. Technically it is, but a very small one at that. Second, you seemed to assign (in your now-deleted commented) a role to garbage collection it doesn't have—that of popping off functions from the execution stack. If these things are errors, wouldn't you like to know? And no, this dialog is not necessary, you're welcome to drop out of the conversation at any time.